# Cisco Router Telnet Connection Refused

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios, cisco-commands

I have a cisco 1941 router just configured but no matter how I go about configuring the telnet, it seems not to work.

It has interfaces already set up and systems can browse through it in the office. It has two interfaces WAN and LAN configured with Ip Addresses and the LAN interface with other sub interfaces with IP address configured on them.

I have tried setting up the terminal with the command as stated below but it is not working.

```
Router(config)#line vty 0 ?
<1-1370> Last Line Number
Router(config-line)#line vty 0 1370
Router(config-line)# password P@$$W)RD
Router(config-line)# login
```

I even tried using the following configuration but yet not working

```
Router(config)#line vty 0 4
Router(config-line)# password P@$$W)RD
Router(config-line)# login
```

Everytime I try to connect to the any of the subinterfaces through telnet or the WAN address through telnet, I get the error message

```
MacBook-Pro:~ User$ telnet x.x.x.x
Trying x.x.x.x...
telnet: connect to address x.x.x.1x Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Please what am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Are you in the same LAN of the router?

Comment: Yes... on the same Lan. The system I am connecting from is connected to the subinterface of the Lan. Interface GigabitEthernet 0/1.1

Comment: If you are using subinterfaces I guess you are using VLANs, is the switch properly configured? If you prefer we can switch this conversation on the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations)

Comment: @OlanrewajuT Do you have any ACLs setup on the Router?

Comment: Yes... I have ACLs on the router and are configured correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. When I checked the running configuration on the router, I noticed I have the line below under the line vty 0 4

```
access-list class 23 in
```

All I had to do was to negate the command and everything went back to normal.

Thanks all for your support.

Comment: If this router is sitting on the Internet edge, are you sure you want to negate your ACL that gave some additional protection to you?  Perhaps updating access-list 23 is more appropriate.

Comment: How do you mean? Please explain! The access list has no function on the router.

Comment: @OlanrewajuT, the `access-list class 23 in` on a VTY applies an ACL limiting access to the VTY's. It is best practice to use them to limit management access to the device.

Answer (score 0):

-- at the running configuration in the line vty interface check if the `transport input` is set... if it says `tansport input none`, then go to the line vty interface and write the following command `transport input telnet`.

Answer (score -1):

run this command in your router

```
conf t
line vty 0 4
transport input all
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by editing it to add more details to make it more useful both for the original poster and future users. Typically short answers like this could provide reasoning why you believe this is the answer, more explanation about the concepts mentioned, references/links to supporting resources, or applicable examples.

Answer (score -2):

Cisco Router as Cisco access Server:
Remember the CAB-OCTAL-ASYNC cable is rolled. Therefore, you can connect each cable directly to the console ports of devices with RJ-45 interfaces.
Anyway, when you config the ports of this OCTAL-Async you need to start from port 2033 down to 2065 not 2001, 2002, or 2003.

Like this:

AS(config)#interface lo0
AS(config-if)#ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.255
AS(config-if)#exit
AS(config)#ip host r1 2033 10.0.0.1
AS(config)#ip host r2 2034 10.0.0.1
AS(config)#ip host r3 2035 10.0.0.1
AS(config)#ip host sw1 2036 10.0.0.1
AS(config)#ip host sw2 2037 10.0.0.1

then if this works after testing it.

Try setting up the password

Hope this answers or others might have some issue as well.

Comment: This doesn't the original question.